# do this binary numbers have a specific name or property to get them?

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

i want binary number that only have 0's at the beginning or end, for instance,

1111111
01111110
001111111
000111000

but no:

01001
0011101

do they have an specific name or property to get them?

I'm looking for something like linear integer optimization conditions, my solutions must have this form, but i can't think of any condition i can add to ensure that

Regards,

Comment: In integer programming this is called "fixing". We fix `x[0]=0` and `x[N]=0`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with linear programming, i think one possible way could be to  `mask` the number in order to achieves `0`.

Comment: Well, in MIP we are limited to linear constraints. Just encode your binary number as an array of binary (i.e. 0-1) variables. Otherwise the first bit and last bit of an integer variable `K` can also be set to zero by requiring `K >= 2` and `K <= MAXK/2`;

Comment: Sorry, that `K>=2` should be `K is multiple of 2`, or `K=2*J` where `J` is another integer variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something which is not nice to formulate within mixed-integer programs. Most problems involving this are more suitable for alternative methods (SAT-solving, SMT-solving, Constraint-programming).

It can be done of course, but the solver will have some work as the formulation is non-trivial and introduces a lot of binary-variables (and the basic approach of MIP-solvers won't work amazingly here; bad integrality-gap).

I won't give you a complete solution, but some basic idea on how to formulate this and i also indicate how hard and cumbersome it is (there are alternative formulations; actually infinite many; but nothing *much more simple*).

The basic idea here is the following:

- your binary number is constructed from `N` binary-variables

  - let's call them `x`
- you introduce `N` auxiliary binary-variables `l` (left)

  - `l[i] == 1` implicates: every `l[j]` with `i<j` is `0`
- you introduce `N` auxiliary binary-variables `r` (right)

  - `r[i] == 1` implicates: every `r[j]` with `i>j` is `0`
- you add the following constraint for each position `k`:

  - `x[k] == 0` implicates: `l[i] == 1` for `i < k` `OR` `r[i] == 1` for `i>k`
  - idea::

    - if there is a zero somewhere, either all on the left-side or all on the right-side are zeroes (or means: at least one side; but can be both)

To formulate this, you need two more ideas:

- **A:** How to formulate the **equality-check**?
- **B:** How to formulate the **implication**?

  - Remark: `a -> b == not a or b` (propositional calculus)
  - (*this was wrongly stated earlier and corrected by OP*)

These are common in MIP and you will find the solution in many integer-programming books, tutorial and papers. [Here is an example](https://download.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/AIMMS3OM_IntegerProgrammingTricks.pdf) (start with *indicator-variables*).

Another small common formulation:

- if `a` is binary, `b` is binary:

  - `a OR b` is equivalent to: `a+b >= 1` (the latter is a linear-expression ready to use for MIP)

**Remark:** The formulas in my idea-setting above might be wrong in regards to indices (`i vs. i-1, vs. i+1`) and binary-relations (`<`vs. `<=`). You will need to do the actual math yourself and just learn from the idea itself!

**Remark 2:** This kind of constraint is cumbersome in MIP, but more easily formulated within SAT and CP.

Comment: Thankz for point me out in the right direction!! Just a correction: `a -> b == not a or b`